# PasteSpecial from Outlook message

Tags: excel, vba

I have macro which pastes values and is assigned to `ctrl+v`. It works fine to all, except text that is copied from outlook message header. There is a

> Run-time error 1004 "Method 'PasteSpecial' of object 'Range' failed".

Does anyone know why? And how fix it?

I've spent a lot of time to search answer in web but with no result.

My code:

```
Sub Paste_As_Value()
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: If you manually try to copy text from Outlook message header is paste values an option?  If not, then it is probably not an option through code either.

Comment: @KerryJackson No, there is not. There is only paste as text option. Your comment inspire me to modify code and it looks like it works now. Thank you :)

Comment: What is your "selection"? ie  have you a range selected before pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to my problem. There is code:

```
Sub Paste_As_Value()
On Error Resume Next
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
If Err.Number > 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Tekst Unicode", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: yes basically what I asked in the comments. Your first attempt fails because you do selection.pastespecial, and you dont have any selection. On the second attempt (err.number>0), you just paste it in the activesheet, so it falls where your cursor was last time, and that works

Answer (score 0):

If you want better control of the data in the clipboard you could use the code below. You could for instance use this tot test if the header is retrievable as text at all.

You will need to turn on "MS Forms 2.0 Object Library" in the VBA references to use the DataObject.

```
Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject, ClipStr as string

    Set DataObj = New MsForms.DataObject 'dataobject with ability to retrieve data from clipboard

    DataObj.GetFromClipboard ''Gets data from clipboard
    ClipStr = DataObj.GetText(1) ''Get content from dataobj

    msgbox ClipStr
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I would rather not to use any additional references. I found solution to my problem.